# Who is "acting responsibly" in this news article about Russian bombers?

Tags: conjunctions, comprehension, coordination

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/vladimir-putin-sending-russian-bombers-close-us-230353217.html

> So far the Russian incursions into sensitive European airspace have been uneventful, General Breedlove said, with both the Russian pilots and the NATO pilots going up to escort them back to Russian territory **acting responsibly**. But other NATO officials worry privately that the increased incursions could end up in some kind of incident – a mid-air collision, for example – that could ratchet up tensions.

Who is exactly acting responsibly? I don't really understand who they're talking about.

Comment: That is badly written. It seems to mean that the NATO pilots and the Russian pilots go back to Russia territory in a responsible way. But obviously the Russian pilots don't **escort** themselves back, only the NATO pilots **escort** them.

Comment: @CRABOLO: I don't see what's badly written about the passage. "...with both [the Russian pilots] and [the NATO pilots going up to escort them back to Russian territory] acting responsibly."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> both the Russian pilots and the NATO pilots going up to escort them back to Russian territory acting responsibly

**both**

the Russian pilots

**and**

the NATO pilots going up to escort them back to Russian territory

(are) acting responsibly